# Is the given unit conversion possible?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, si-units, unit-conversion

I have to convert from Joule to Newton than to a specific unit, but I 
don't know which two unit factors I have to choose (since I am not allowed to change $kg$) to get the final result:

$$1\,{\rm J} = 1\,{\rm N\,m} = 10^6 \cdot \frac{\rm kg \cdot \_\,m^2}{ \_\,^2}$$

My main problem is to get the $10^6$, I tried many possible combinations but I always failed.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Comment: FWIW, the fact that this is a HW question is probably where the downvotes came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what the point of this is, but my guess for the conversion would be:
$ 1N = 1 \frac{kg\cdot m}{s^2}$, thus
$$ 1J=1Nm=1\frac{kg\cdot m^2}{s^2}=10^6\frac{kg\cdot m^2}{10^6\cdot s^2} $$

Comment: I see! I thought that i had to achieve $10^6$ by converting the units... I really thank you!(i cannot upvote, because i am new, sorry!)

Comment: .Is a conversion to the given term with $10^6$ as a constant factor, only based on changing the units, possible? I think its not possible because of the $\_^2$, but i am not sure.

Comment: Principally yes, you could also put 10^3 together with s^2 inside brackets, like (10^3*s)^2. The basic algebraic rules apply.
Any combination of powers which will cancel out 10^6 is allowed.
Maybe it would make more sense if you could put the 10^6 to the mass, i.e. convert kg to mg